# trigger vi mode key binding in normal mode only

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, bashrc, readline, vi-mode

**I've created some custom key bindings for bash vi mode. They trigger while I'm in insert mode and I want them instead to trigger when I'm in normal mode.**

I'm using vi mode

```
set -o vi
```

in a terminal emulator on Ubuntu 14.04 server. So far I have remapped:

> ^ — Move to start of line
>
> $ — Move to end of line

To the following:

> `<space>`a — Move to start of line
>
> `<space>`; — Move to end of line

Using the bash built-in command [bind](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/bind1.html) by editing **.bashrc** as follows:

```
bind " -a":beginning-of-line
bind " -;":end-of-line
```

These key bindings work - but they only trigger when I'm in insert mode. How do I get them only to fire **only when I'm in normal mode and not in insert mode**, instead?

tags: bash vi mode, bash vi mode remap keys, vi mode normal mode

Comment: How would you expect the interface to be able to determine when `<space>a` is intended to send the cursor to the start of the line rather than a literal space followed by an `a`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti It does this already, though not perfectly. The bindings shown work correctly - though pressing the spacebar in normal mode and insert mode advances the cursor by default - it doesn't matter in this case because you'll still end up at either the beginning or end of the line as intended.

Comment: You should remap those in `~/.inputrc` and you can then distinguish between `vi-command` and `vi-insert`.

Comment: @jasonwryan You're right. I just saw that on the vim wiki http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_vi_shortcuts_in_terminal. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**This is how its done in .inputrc:**

```
set editing-mode vi
$if mode=vi

# these are for vi-command mode
set keymap vi-command

# unbind space
" ": ""

# bind space-a, space-;
" a":beginning-of-line
" ;":"$" 

$endif
```